# Rendering multiple instances in Handlebars+Express+Nodejs

Tags: node.js, html-parsing, rendering, express-handlebars, templating-engine

please help me with following: how to render multiple instances which are comming from anydata base (in my case from Gcloud datastore, before it was MongoDB but it does not actually matter), as i understand Handlebars can accept/parse objects or array or objects, so now im doing this way Im importing functions that returns a promise

```
const someFunction = require('from somewhere');

 somedatabase query (err, apiResponse) => {
        >>> someFunction ().then(someFunctionResponse=> {
                res.render('index', {
                    x: apiResponse,
                    y: someFunctionResponse,
                   });
        });
    })
```

im using one inside other, Is this a right way ? I dont see any other way to resolve promise and pass it to res.render

It works fine but just to be sure / more professional

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to use `Promise.all()` thats it. In case